# SQL query to display all tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL Developer. How do I write a SQL query to display all tables in the database and the name of the table, and number of rows?

Comment: If you have access, try looking at this table:  dba_tables

Comment: the title is too long and description is too short!

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following,

if you want to view all the tables that your account has access to,

- `select table_name, num_rows counter from all_tables`

If you only want to view tables you own,

- `SELECT table_name, num_rows counter FROM user_tables`

If you have access to the DBA_TABLES data dictionary view,

- `SELECT table_name, num_rows counter FROM dba_tables`

Comment: You're right provided that the tables have fresh statistics.